# CORS issue with one WCF call but not another?

Tags: javascript, wcf, cors, wcf-data-services

We have two HTML pages that consume two WCF calls. Both WCF methods are under the same project, and when deployed, under `http://MyServer:89`. We've had no issues with CORS since `web.config` has the following:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept"/>
  </customHeaders>
```

The `[OperationContract]` look like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    UriTemplate = "GetData")]
System.IO.Stream GetData();

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    UriTemplate = "GetMoreData")]
System.IO.Stream GetMoreData();
```

Both HTML pages are also in the same server but different port (`http://MyServer:93`).

`GetData()` is called by an HTML with AM Charts javascript controls. The call looks something like this and it's been working great the past few months:

```
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "http://MyServer:89/Service1.svc/GetData",
```

Just today I created `GetMoreData()` for another HTML page. The function call looks like this:

```
    var serviceUri = "http://MyServer:89/Service1.svc/GetMoreData";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: serviceUri,
        dataType: "json",
        success:
            function (response) {
                showPresidentsList(response);
                $('#message').html("<a href=" + serviceUri + ">" + serviceUri + "</a>");
            },
        error:
            function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
    });
```

This second call was giving me CORS issues, specifically the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at     
'http://MyServer:89/Service1.svc/GetMoreData' from origin     
'http://MyServer:93' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight     
request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The solution was to add a wildcard for the web invoke method, instead of just `GET`:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
UriTemplate = "GetMoreData")]
System.IO.Stream GetMoreData();
```

My question: why would one have this CORS issue but the other doesn't since they're both under the same IP:Port?

Comment: Hmm.  Not all requests trigger a CORS pre-flight request.  See [MDN: CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)  (scroll down to "Simple Requests").  I suspect the first request is a simple request, but the second isn't, though I'm not sure what the difference between the requests is.

Comment: Is your first request made the same way?  You are specifying `contentType: "application/json",`, which is not one of the "simple request" allowed header values.  If the first request doesn't have that header, that might be the difference.

Answer (score 0):

How do you send the first request? There might be something different from this JS invocation.
Besides, please attempt the below solution of the CORS issue. We have to handle the OPTION request. Please add the below code to Global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

And the webconfig.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.